# how to display one mxml in another

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

I have one mxml file that process xml,  and  display the graphics on panel.
I need to display first mxml in another mxml file, in some area(HBox, VBox, Panel,  dont care). How i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

The question sounds too simple so I am wondering if I missed something? Why not make the first mxml a child inside the HBox/VBox?

```
<AnotherMXML>
  <VBox>
       <FirstMXMLComponent/>    
  </VBox>
</AnotherMXML>
```

Comment: I tried, but i  had this kind of error:ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.